# Laptop shuts down when not plugged in

Tags: boot, power-management, shutdown, battery

I have a dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 18.04 laptop and have been unable to solve the dilemma of why it shuts down anytime I am not plugged in.

At first I thought I'd forgot and battery died.  But everytime I start it I cannot boot from grub menu straight to Ubuntu. I have to run the recovery and dpkg, then I have to completely shut the power down in order to get back into Ubuntu.

If I don't, a black screen flickers after kubuntu flash screen and cursor is not flashing at top left side of screen.

Shutting down and retrying after dpkg and shut down again, a black screen shows a flashing cursor, then the arrow cursor appears, which lets me know Ubuntu will load to login screen this time.

Battery is 100% charged when this happens or less, but never dead. I have set all power management settings to never timeout etc. but cannot figure out what is causing it.

When plugged in, I can close laptop, keep it open, etc. and it never happens for days. I do not know how to read logs to see if something is causing this.

UPDATE: Not sure how this relates, but yesterday I noticed battery level at 83% for over an hour. Rebooted, battery at 83% and fully charged within a short time. Today, have been plugged in for over 3hours with lid closed; opening laptop, battery still at 86% (what it had prior to closing). Now after 30 minutes, battery still at 86%, plugged in. Since this does not happen in Win 10 I am unsure why it does not show charge advancing.

```
lspci -v:

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Memory behind bridge: dc000000-dd0fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000c1ffffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer HD Graphics 530
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
        Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 60000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
        Memory at dd310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
        Memory at dd32e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
        Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
        Memory at dd32d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
        Memory at dd328000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Memory at dd32c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at dd32b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: dd200000-dd2fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
        Memory behind bridge: dd100000-dd1fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
        Memory behind bridge: c4000000-da0fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000a1ffffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H PMC
        Flags: fast devsel
        Memory at dd324000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 128
        Memory at dd320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at dd300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H SMBus
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
        Memory at dd32a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
        Memory at dc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at dd000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 1501
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at dd080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
        Memory at dd200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi

04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
        Memory at dd115000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Expansion ROM at dd100000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
        Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Memory at dd114000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at dd110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Bus: primary=05, secondary=06, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
        Memory behind bridge: c4000000-da0fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000a1ffffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: da000000-da0fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
        Bus: primary=06, secondary=08, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
        Memory behind bridge: c4000000-d9efffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000a1ffffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Bus: primary=06, secondary=3d, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: d9f00000-d9ffffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

3d:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge] (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
        Memory at d9f00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Comment: How can we help you, if we don't even know your hardware?  Since it works on Thinkpad, it must be surely some acpi problem, we have to tackle. So please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260636/edit) you question and add the information of `lspci -v`.

Comment: I don't know about Thinkpad (I do not own one). But shutdown doesn't happen in W10, only Linux.